# Realm debug symbols missing?

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, realm

I'm working on an iOS app that uses Realm which is installed/managed via Cocoapods. My app crashes sporadically and I'm having difficulty troubleshooting the problem because my stack trace doesn't show me the method names related to Realm.  I am deploying a debug build of my app to the phone via Xcode and I have the Debug Information Format option set to DWARF with dSYM File.  In the stack trace below you can see that my code appears to be symbolicated but the method names in Realm are just addresses and offsets.  Unfortunately, I'm somewhat new to troubleshooting with Xcode but I'm under the assumption that this means the Realm debug symbols could not be found?  If anyone can explain to me how to correct this, I'd really appreciate it!

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x18316ad8c __exceptionPreprocess + 228
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1823245ec objc_exception_throw + 55
2   Realm                           0x10814e238 0x108030000 + 1172024
3   Realm                           0x10814ffa0 0x108030000 + 1179552
4   Realm                           0x10814ff74 0x108030000 + 1179508
5   MyAppName                       0x104af31a4 closure #1 in closure #2 in processOutgoingMessage(outgoingMessage:) + 4452772 (ProcessOutgoingMessage.swift:51)
6   MyAppName                       0x1046cd168 _T0Ieg_IeyB_TR + 102760 (DataSource.swift:0)
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x182a5caa0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 23
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x182a5ca60 _dispatch_client_callout + 15
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x182a9dd80 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$armv81 + 963
10  CoreFoundation                  0x183113070 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 11
11  CoreFoundation                  0x183110bc8 __CFRunLoopRun + 2271
12  CoreFoundation                  0x183030da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 551
13  GraphicsServices                0x185015020 GSEventRunModal + 99
14  UIKit                           0x18d04d758 UIApplicationMain + 235
15  MyAppName                       0x104a7919c main + 3953052 (AppDelegate.swift:18)
16  libdyld.dylib                   0x182ac1fc0 start + 3
```

**UPDATE** - as it turns out, the Build Settings for the Pods project (recall that I'm using Realm via Cocoapods) needed to also have the Debug Information Format set to DWARF with dSYM File for debug builds.  My app hasn't crashed again yet but I did notice that when I cleaned and rebuilt the app this time it appeared to be including the debug symbols for Realm so here's hoping.